# using an Array in a GET request

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which looks like this `languages = [1,2,3,4,5]`

The API call expects the url parameter to be `languages=1&languages=2&...`

how can I achieve this with javascript?

I've tried `JSON.stringify(languages);` & just sending the `languages` variable, but I don't get the desired result.

I can also loop over the array and always add `&languages=number` to a string, but I figured the would be a more efficient way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: More efficient way would be sending the array via POST or PUT call..

Comment: @MaanusIndov If it's a request for something then it should be a GET.  We don't know that it is, but it certainly looks like it is.

Comment: @Archer well, its true that it's nice to use GET if you request to get some data, but there is no rule that you MUST use it

Its true that we don't know what for the request is used, it can easily be an update or save call also, as for some item and it's languages, or even a delete call for what languages to be removed, options are limitless :)

Comment: It's more than "nice" to use GET.  It defines the HTTP request by type, so the developer writing the server-side code knows exactly what the request means.  If you start using POST requests to get data then you immediately lose all clarity.  Problems caused by shortcuts are limitless :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option using [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var languages = [2,4,6,8]

lang_params = 'languages='+languages.join('&languages=')

console.log(lang_params)
```

(as per @Quentin and @Amit comments) If you work with other params that are not integer, you might need to encode the values so they don't interfere with special symbols (i.e. `&`,`?`). In such case, you can use [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
lang_params = languages.map((l)=>'languages='+encodeURIComponent(l)).join('&')
```

Comment: a "cleaner" version would be `languages.map(lang => 'languages=' + lang).join('&')`. no biggie though...

Comment: Thanks @Amit, edited answer to match your suggestion on the second part

Answer (score 2):

The [`URISearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API will handle this case cleanly.

It will also do any escaping of the data that is required to make the values or keys URL safe (in your particular example this doesn't matter, but it is worth paying attention to for the general case).

```js
// Create an object to describe the data in the query string
var query = new URLSearchParams();

// Add the languages
var languages = [1,2,3,4,5]
languages.forEach(function (language) {
    query.append("language", language);
});

// Explicitly convert to a string
console.log(query.toString());
```

Note there is [limited browser support at present](http://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams), so you will probably wish to use [a polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params).